# Cluster lat and lon points in python

Tags: python, cluster-analysis

I have a phpmyadminn database containing several thousand lat and lon points obtained from images on flickr. These images are all based around the main cities in the world, and I am looking for a simple clustering algorithm in python that could find where most of these images in each city are clustered.

The idea is that a point on the map where many lat and lon points are clustered will correspond possibly to a place of interest or a landmark within the city.

I know this question is quite broad, but I would really just appreciate anyone sending me in the right direction. I am new to python and even databases so I am quite lost at the minute. A simple algorithm that is easy to follow would suit me best.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: @Anony-Mousse if you read my question I am asking for a suggestion of a clustering algorithm to use so there is no need for such a rude comment, I have flagged the comment.

Comment: @Anony-Mousse I am simply asking for the name of a clustering algorithm you are possibly one of the rudest and most unhelpful people I've come across if you have can't help just don't comment